# PHP Cookie not saved after foreach

Tags: php, cookies

I can not save a cookie after a foreach. Before the foreach the cookie is saved perfectly.

For example, this works fine:

```
<?php
setcookie('test', 'This is a test', time() + 3600 , '/', '.mydomain.com');    

if(isset($_COOKIE['test'])){
   echo 'The cookie is ' . $_COOKIE['test'];
} else {
   echo 'No cookie has been set';
}

foreach ($values as $value){  
  // CODE
  echo $value;
}
?>
```

But with this code, I can't save the cookie:

```
<?php
foreach ($values as $value){  
  // CODE
  echo $value;
}

setcookie('test', 'This is a test', time() + 3600 , '/', '.mydomain.com');    

if(isset($_COOKIE['test'])){
   echo 'The cookie is ' . $_COOKIE['test'];
} else {
   echo 'No cookie has been set';
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `//CODE` do? If it emits anything then you cannot send a `Set-Cookie` HTTP header unless you buffer your output appropriately.

Comment: Show info with echo

Comment: In which case you cannot set a cookie, as once you've sent information in the content it's too late to send an HTTP header.

Comment: *Heyyy..* exactly! A *echo* already sends the headers, so it can't send the `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: And how I can clear the HTTP header? I need to set the cookie after the foreach

Comment: @kurtko do not use echo ?

Comment: If you [look at how HTTP works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session), you will see why you cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: Read this thread, this is for redirecting mostly. *But..* the same idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Thanks, finally solved with ob_start / ob_end_flush

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can only be set BEFORE OUTPUT... therefore if you are outputting in your foreach loop, cookies can not be set afterwards.

However, I believe you can actually use output buffers to work around this problem... So the following should work just fine...

```
ob_start();
setcookie(...);
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: The buffer needs to be started before your first `echo` call.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved with this code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
foreach ($values as $value){  
  // CODE
  echo $value;
}

setcookie('test', 'This is a test', time() + 3600 , '/', '.mydomain.com'); 
ob_end_flush();    

if(isset($_COOKIE['test'])){
   echo 'The cookie is ' . $_COOKIE['test'];
} else {
   echo 'No cookie has been set';
}
?>
```

Comment: Great! I can advise to structure your code in a way that you won't need that next time though, It's (almost) always possible through proper structure.